# Type char as numeric type

Tags: java

I've got specific two questions about char type in java.
Is char type in java a numeric type which includes natural numbers?

Is this sentence true?
Variable of type char does not require conversion when assigning to types short, int, long, float

Comment: *"Is char type in java a numeric type which includes natural numbers?"* - well it can contain a natural number, e.g. 17, but it cannot contain all natural numbers obviously.

Comment: `char` in Java is a two byte unsigned integer type.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to the [Primitive Data Types doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), a Java char is a decimal representation of a Unicode character, and it ranges from 0 to 65535. From the [Unicode chart](https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/%7Etomw/java/unicode.html) we can see, for example, that the decimal representation of 'a' is the number 97, so the following prints "true":

```
System.out.print('a' == 97);
```